# Object $LogProvider has no method debugEnabled

Tags: angularjs, debugging, uncaught-exception, nosuchmethod

When using the following lines of code on my Angular module `myApp`:

```
myApp.config(function ($logProvider) {
    $logProvider.debugEnabled(true);
});
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<$LogProvider> has no method 'debugEnabled' from myApp core.ts:6
(anonymous function) core.ts:6
invoke angular.js:2990
(anonymous function) angular.js:2914
forEach angular.js:130
loadModules angular.js:2900
createInjector angular.js:2842
doBootstrap angular.js:1037
bootstrap angular.js:1052
angularInit angular.js:1010
(anonymous function) angular.js:15154
jQuery.Callbacks.fire jquery-1.9.1.js:1037
jQuery.Callbacks.self.fireWith jquery-1.9.1.js:1148
jQuery.extend.ready jquery-1.9.1.js:433
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It depends on how/when/where you use those lines. Posting more code (or better yet preparing a fiddle) might help. The lines by themselves are perfectly fine and should work (if used properly).

Comment: Is it inside a test suite?

Answer (score 0):

Use the version property:

```
angular.version.full
```

to compare the version in question to the version in which this API was synced between the `mock` and `ng` modules:

> 1.2.0rc1 spooky-giraffe (2013-08-13) keep mock.$log the api in sync with $log

**References**

- [AngularJS Changelog](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)
- [The $logProvider mock doesn't implement $log.debug() and debugEnabled() in version 1.1.x #2343](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2343)